# Query for before or after the characters

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using Sqlite for a personal application and I have got a simple query

```
Select Name from Employees where Name (Name LIKE '%aj%')
```

It returns me results

```
Pankaj
Neeraj
Saajan
```

but this query

```
Select Name from Employees where Name (Name LIKE 'aj%')
```

doesn't returns anything, I guess It should returns

```
Pankaj
Neeraj
```

as they both ends with 'aj'. I want all the entries which ends with 'aj'.

Couldn't figure out whats wrong here or Sqlite doesn't support single ampersand (%) queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Name from Employees where Name LIKE '%aj'
```

You should place your wildcard in front of the wanted chars.

[A wildcard character can be used to substitute for any other character(s) in a string.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Comment: I thought That Putting % in front of finds search starting with "wanted chars" and putting % at back finds search ends with "wanted chars". I was trying to find the records with ends with aj

Comment: No, the wildcard or allquantor means, that there can be any chars instead of the wildcard.